# From Bash I would like to use find to execute 2 commands on the same file, so I can output the file name and metadata about the file

Tags: bash, find

From bash I need to execute 2 commands on specific files recursively. I am trying to print the filename and meta information at the same time. I need to combine the following 2 commands so first a filename is printed, then the metadata for that file is printed, and then repeat for the next file.

I print the file name with:

`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo {} \;`

And I print the meta-data with:

`find . -wholename ‘*word/test\.wsp’ -exec whisper-info {} \;`

However, the second command does not print the filename, so I am unsure which files the meta-data belongs to.

How can I execute the 2 commands simutaneously?

I've tried:
`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo {} && whisper-info {} \;`
`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo && whisper-info {} \;`
`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo {} && -exec whisper-info {} \;`
`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo {} \; && whisper-info {} \;`
`find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp -exec echo {} \; && -exec whisper-info {} \;`

And a lot of other combinations.

Comment: You might use `find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp' -print -exec whisper-info {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-exec` require a single command, but that command can be a shell that executes an arbitrary script consisting of your two commands.

```
find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp' -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; whisper-info "$1"' _ {} \;
```

A few notes:

- `{}` is not embedded in the command. Let the command be a *static* script that accepts an argument, instead.
- `_` is a dummy value used to set `$0` in the shell.

You can avoid spawning quite so many shells by including a loop in the shell to iterate over multiple arguments provided by `find -exec ... +`

```
find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp' -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "$f"; whisper-info "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

`for f; do ...; done` is short for `for f in "$@"; do ...; done`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put two `-exec`s.

```
find . -wholename '*word/test.wsp' -exec echo {} \; -exec whisper-info {} \;
```

If you have GNU `find`, perhaps prefer its built-in `printf` rather than an external `echo`.

You also consistently seem to have misplaced the closing quote. The string with the wildcard needr to be quoted or escaped to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard before `find` runs.

Comment: Huh, thought I had added this to my answer as well, but apparently I forgot to save the change. Have an upvote :)